# Oversight: an inadvertent omission or error

Tags: etymology, historical-change

What is the origin of the word ***oversight***, in this context ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oversight)):

- An inadvertent omission or error

It would be my guess that the word did not always have this as one of its meanings.

It would almost seem as though someone, somewhere needed a softened/blurred/obscured way to say "I accidentally screwed up, because I wan't looking where I should have been looking".

This would be similar to a definition of ***overshoot*** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overshoot)):

- To shoot or go over, beyond, or above; miss

Comment: Have you checked [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=oversight)?

Comment: Today we use _overlook_, not _oversee_, as a verb meaning to unintentionally fail to notice some object or perform some action. But I imagine that long ago _oversee_ was used in the sense of _overlook_. In any event, the American Heritage Dictionary, fifth edition (2011), reports that _oversight_ in the sense of "an unintentional omission or mistake" is older in English than _oversight_ in the sense of "watchful care or management; supervision."

Comment: @SvenYargs Care to post this as an answer?

Comment: I'll see whether I can find anything more on the dictionary histories of both _oversee/oversight_ and _overlook_. If something conclusive (or interesting) turns up, I'll try to post a real answer based on that research. As currently written, however, my comment above is too sketchy (in the sense of "like a sketch") and speculative to justify posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Early dictionary definitions of 'oversee', 'overlook', and 'oversight'***

The dual (and dueling) meanings of *oversee* go back quite a long way in English usage, as do the corresponding pair of meanings of *overlook* (although *overlook* also had a third meaning along the lines of ""to view contemptuously"). Here are the relevant entries in John Kersey, [*Dictionarium Anglo-Britannicum: Or, A General English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=t01gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT504&dq=%22full+Moon+which+comes+before+any+great+moveable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI_YvMm8_YxgIVBouSCh1Ungh4#v=onepage&q=%22to%20have%20an%20Eye%22&f=false) (1708):

> To **Over-look,** to have an Eye upon, to wink at ; to take no notice of ; to look upon with disdain.
>
> ...
>
> To **Oversee,** to have the Management of ; to over-look, or let slip.

And here are the corresponding entries in Nathan Bailey, [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UeUIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT585&dq=%22Overlook+to+look+over+to+have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7rcHp3KXWAhUG4GMKHXN1A_gQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Overlook%20to%20look%20over%20to%20have%22&f=false), second edition (1724):

> To OVERLOOK, to look over, to have an Eye upon, or look after ; to take no notice of, to wink at ; to look upon with Contempt.
>
> ...
>
> To OVERSEE, to have the Management of ; to overlook or let pass.

Bailey's dictionary seems to owe a considerable unacknowledged debt to Kersey's. Neither of these dictionaries has an entry for the noun *oversight*.

Slightly earlier than Kersey's solo dictionary is his revision of Edward Philips's *New World of Words*, which has a rather more garbled entry for "To Over-look" but virtually the same one for "To Over-see." From Phillips & Kersey, [*The New World of Words: Or, Universal English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PHBUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT246&hl=en#v=onepage&q=%22to%20have%20an%20eye%20upon%22&f=false), sixth edition (1706):

> To **Over-look,** to have an Eye upon, to survey , to connive or wink at ; to pass by, or take no notice of ; to over-top, to look upon with disdain or scorn.
>
> ...
>
> To **Over-see,** to have the Conduct or Management of ; to over-look, or let slip.

The noun *oversight* finally appears in yet another Kersey dictionary, [*A New English Dictionary: Or, a Compleat Collection of the Most Proper and Significant Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=305gAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Collection+of+the+Most+Proper+and+Significant+Words%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEsbOy7qXWAhVKh1QKHdN7AZEQ6AEIKDAA#v=snippet&q=%22a%20looking%20after%22&f=false), second edition (1713)—and the two inconsistent meanings are in place:

> An **Oversight**, a looking after a Business , a Mistake.

So, to sum up, oversight has had the meanings "business supervision or management" and "a mistake" for more than 300 years. The associated verb *oversee* and its synonym *overlook* have likewise carried rather incompatible dual meanings for more than three centuries as well.

---

***The trouble with 'over'-***

The culprit here is the prefix *over-*, which has a number of meanings that run in several directions. Here is the discussion of *over-* in Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: A Dictionary of Word Beginnings and Endings* (2002):

> **over-** *Excessively; extra; outer; above.* {English *over*.}
>
> The form has several of the senses of the preposition *over* and appears in a very large number of compounds that can be nouns, adjectives, verbs, or adverbs. **Over-** can be freely prefixed to other words for a momentary need. Its meanings are rather variable and diffuse, and difficult to categorize.
>
> Having said that, there are some groupings that are commonly encountered. The one most often found refers to something beyond what is usual or desirable, even excessively so (***overambitious***, ***overcareful***, ***overexert***, ***overindulgence***, ***overfull***, ***overprecise***, ***overprepared***, ***overweight***), which leads into a rarer sense of 'utterly' or 'completely' (***overawed***, ***overjoyed***). In others, the form has a spatial sense of something above or higher up, which broadens into a figurative sense of something that is superior (***overhang***, ***overbridge***, ***overarching***, ***overlook***, ***overtone***, ***overlord***, ***overrule***). A fourth set of words in which the meaning is of something upper, outer, or extra (***overcoat***, ***overshoes***, ***overtime***). Another sense is of motion forward and down, and hence of inversion (***overturning***, ***overbalance***, ***overthrow***, ***overboard***). The form can also suggest covering a surface (***overpaint***, **overgrow**).

Evidently, *oversee*, *overlook*, and *oversight* long ago acquired meanings that invoke both the "excessively" sense of *over-* and the "above" sense of *over-*. The result is three words whose own meanings seem to be fundamentally hostile to one other.